# Vertical Section in angular card

Tags: angular, mat-card

I'm trying to duplicate a mat-card layout and haven't found the right words to search yet. I'm using angular and want to set up a mat-card that has a vertical section on the left hand side which allows me to put a logo that is centered on the section line. I've included a sample image that I'm trying to recreate. [example card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOOVT.png)

My Card

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="flex-container" fxLayout="row">
        <mat-card>
            <aside>

            </aside>
            <mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-title>{{project.name | uppercase}}</mat-card-title>
                <mat-card-subtitle>{{project.location}}</mat-card-subtitle>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>
                <section>
                    Last Scan: {{project.lastScanDate | date: 'shortDate'}}
                </section>
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried adding an "aside" but that doesn't show up unless I include text.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Show what you have tried so far? post your code

Comment: I haven't really tried anything because I'm not sure what to call the vertical section. So really, I've only tried googling...

Comment: this is not how SO works, we can help you to achieve by suggesting or improving your code, noone will trite it for you

Comment: apologies.. but I'm looking for suggestions because I have no idea what will accomplish what I'm looking for. I have edited my post to at least include my html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is just a raw example of what you want, you can change the icon image by putting your image URL in css,  so this is just an iea how you can do what you want. change the things as per your need.

```css
.flex-container {background: #ccc; padding: 20px 0 0;border-radius: 5px; box-sizing: border-box; border-left: 25px solid #5243AA; min-height: 150px;}
mat-card {display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between;min-height: 150px; padding-left: 20px;}
mat-card-content {margin-left: -20px; background: #fff; padding: 10px;     box-shadow: 1px 3px 7px -1px #ddd;}

mat-card-title {position: relative;}
mat-card-title:after {position: absolute; content: ""; height: 20px; width: 20px; left: -30px; top: 0; background-image: url(https://img.favpng.com/21/1/24/arrow-icon-circle-icon-direction-icon-png-favpng-Lmfw1dQK3ZtSWQX1kUmGXEPVh.jpg); background-size: cover;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="flex-container" fxLayout="row">
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>{{project.name | uppercase}}</mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-subtitle>{{project.location}}</mat-card-subtitle>
        <mat-card-content>
            <section>
                Last Scan: {{project.date | date: 'shortDate'}}
            </section>
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: super! Thank you! Seems I was googling for sections and vertical lines when I should have looking for border. I appreciate your help! This worked well!

Comment: always happy to help